# all of sports or sports of all

Tags: word-usage

> Each  of  these  offers  **water-sports  of  all  kinds**  as  well  as snorkelling and scuba diving around the numerous coral reefs that line Malaysia's shore.

I am so confused with the phrase  **water-sports  of  all  kinds** in this sentence. I found the usage "all kinds of Xs" most.

Does it say **the different types of water sports** or
**suprising kinds of water sports**?

Comment: Semantically, “Xs of all kinds” = “all kinds of Xs”.

Answer (score 1):

You can say either "water-sports of all kinds" or "all kinds of water-sports", without any difference in meaning.

However, the latter is a litte more common and idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

"Of all kinds" is closer to "different types of" but suggests that the types are representative of all of the available kinds possible (which is to say if there were "surprising kinds" of water sports [and the extract doesn't suggest there is or isn't] then one should reasonably expect some representative selection of these to be included in something described as "all kinds").

It is tends to mean closer to a "myriad of" or "different types of" though because no one actually expects a mathematical rigour of the speaker and instead some amount of hyperbole in the usage is to be expected. Thus "all kinds of" most literally means "many kinds of" or to use a real equivalent phrase "all manner of" (note though that this features an uncommon usage of "manner").